# convert number with decimal places from char to int in c++

Tags: c++

I was playing around with VS 2012 and came across a very tricky problem (for me at least). I have a simple program that does mathematical   operations on inputs from the command line. However, if you input arguments with decimal places somewhere in the program it seems to forget the numbers after the decimal place.

```
double add (char const *inp, char const *inp2) {        //addition function
    double val = std::strtol(inp, NULL, 0);
    double val2 = std::strtol(inp2, NULL, 0);
    return val + val2;
}
```

and then calling the function :

```
double result = add(argv[1], argv[2]);
printf("%f \n", result);
```

and call from command line

```
test 52.2 44.6
```

returns 96 instead of 96.8.

Comment: @rici: this should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @rici oh yeah,     strtod     would probably preferable for doubles! thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yeah, I guess you're right. I was being lazy.

Comment: BTW: the question is wrong, you want "char to double" not "char to int".

Comment: @JefferyThomas yeah, should of been clearer. anyway I see my fault now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `strtod`, not `strtol`. `strtol` only parses integers.

`strtod` only takes two arguments, because floating point numbers are always in base 10 (as far as `strtod` is concerned, anyway.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you answer this already. I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are turning your strings into longs (I'm guessing that's what strtol() is...). I was building a calculator and I had that problem - I wrote a function to handel it:

```
double string_to_double(string str)
{
    int length = (int)str.length();
    double output = 0; //This holds value of output.  Will be added for each 10's digit
    int decimalPos = length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(str.at(i) == '.') // Find if there is a decimal point
        {
            decimalPos = i - 1; //Sets Decimal Position
            str.erase(str.begin()+i);
            length--;
        }
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        switch (str.at(i))
        {
            case '1':
                output += 1*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '2':
                output += 2*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '3':
                output += 3*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '4':
                output += 4*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '5':
                output += 5*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '6':
                output += 6*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '7':
                output += 7*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '8':
                output += 8*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '9':
                output += 9*pow(10, decimalPos - i);
                break;
            case '0':
                break;
        }

    }
    return output;
}
```

...but there is probably a better way

Comment: Yup, Jeffery's is way better :)

Comment: it is an interesting take on the issue. But I'll take the 'strtod'   way out

Comment: While it's always good to understand what library functions do, you'll usually find that they do it better. For example, `strtod` works hard to minimize computation errors, in order to satisfy the accuracy requirements (which are effectively that the result must be one of the three closest representable values). That's hard to do, and a naïve implementation won't come close.

Comment: Yea, I figured there was something that did it for me but I had looked around for half an hour and not found anything. so I just did it myself.